# Line return problem when editing free fields notes with another program

Tags: c#, sql-server, sage

I need to make an application editing notes on a database sage 100 Cloud.

When I modify the note (Table dbo.F_COMPTETNOTE, column CT_Note) the new lines are recorded but do not appear in sage gescom.

- My application is written in C# .NET 6.0
- The database is collated with `French_CI_AS`

Did you have any idea why I have this problem apart the simple response "Encoding problem"?

connection is of type SqlConnection from lib Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
the query with the problem is

```
request = "UPDATE F_COMPTETNOTE SET CT_Note = @Content, cbModification = @cbModification WHERE CT_Num = @CT_Num";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(request, Program.connection.conn);
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Content", SqlDbType.VarChar);
p1.LocaleId = 0x040c;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1).Value = cleanText;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cbModification", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = timeString;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CT_Num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NoteId;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;
int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

I already forced conversion from Utf16 to Utf-8 or ANSI or latin1 but nothing seem to work

## Edit1:

Table structure

```
USE [PROJI13]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE]    Script Date: 12/02/2024 18:04:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE](
    [CT_Num] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [cbCT_Num]  AS (CONVERT([varbinary](18),[CT_Num])),
    [CT_Note] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [cbProt] [smallint] NULL,
    [cbMarq] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cbCreateur] [char](4) NULL,
    [cbModification] [datetime] NULL,
    [cbReplication] [int] NULL,
    [cbFlag] [smallint] NULL,
    [cbCreation] [datetime] NULL,
    [cbCreationUser] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CBMARQ_F_COMPTETNOTE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cbMarq] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [ICT_NOTE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [cbCT_Num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [cbProt]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT ('CSQL') FOR [cbCreateur]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2](0),getdate())) FOR [cbModification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [cbReplication]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [cbFlag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2](0),getdate())) FOR [cbCreation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKA_F_COMPTETNOTE_CT_Num] FOREIGN KEY([CT_Num])
REFERENCES [dbo].[F_COMPTET] ([CT_Num])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_COMPTETNOTE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKA_F_COMPTETNOTE_CT_Num]
GO
```

Comment: What string values are you sending in? And why aren't you using NVARCHAR

Comment: *If* the datatype of `CT_Num` is a `varchar`, then passing an `nvarchar` would be *terrible* for performance, @siggemannen . Though, with a name like `CT_Num`, I'd expect it to be *numerical*...

Comment: I mean, why isn't he using NVARCHAR for CT_Note. The "locale" thing looks very suspect

Comment: What do you means by "new lines" as well? Are you saying that the database shows a different value to the application?

Comment: What value has "ret" after an update?

Comment: See Update with table structure

Comment: *"the table is as follow"* there is an [edit] feature, please use it.

Comment: Your used types are suspicious. What type is NoteId? And if cbModification is a datetime why you use varchar as parameter type. Can't remember but shouldn't that throw an Exception when calling ExecuteNonQuery? Are you catching exceptions in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the correct approach is as follow

1. pass an DateTime object rater than the string representation replace
2. the eventual \r by nothing and after replace the \n by \r

```
DateTime dt = TimeProcess.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(TimeProcess.TimeStampUnix());

string  request = "UPDATE F_COMPTETNOTE SET CT_Note = @Content, cbModification = @cbModification WHERE CT_Num = @CT_Num";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(request, Program.connection.conn);
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Content", SqlDbType.VarChar);
p1.LocaleId = 0x040c;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1).Value = cleanText.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "\r");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cbModification", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CT_Num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NoteId;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;
int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```